# Grails Jasper Plugin error

Tags: grails, jasper-plugin

I have installed the plugin for Jasper 1.6.1 and can see it in my plugin's directory.  However according to, http://grails.org/plugin/jasper, it says when you are running your app, test the plugin by going to (app-url)/jasper/demo.  When I try that, it doesn't work.  I am pretty sure I'm missing something, but the document doesn't say.  Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to display with the URL below. Oddly enough, the URL is case sensitive so you have to capitalize the D in jasperDemo...

```
http://localhost:8080/testGrailsProject01/jasperDemo/demo
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin doc's are wrong. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/sebastianhohns/grails-jasper/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/jasper/JasperDemoController.groovy) what exists is a `JasperDemoController` so I think you can access though the url: `jasperdemo/demo`